# Access Grid.Columnspan from StoryBoard

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a ListView which occupies to cells of Grid:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListView
        x:Name="itemListView"
        Grid.Column="0"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        />
</Grid>
```

I wanted to change colspan in Storyboard:

```
<VisualState x:Name="Snapped">
    <Storyboard>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
            Storyboard.TargetName="itemListView"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Grid.ColumnSpan">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1" />
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

But it ended up in runtime error...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is pretty simple, but not obvious (well, at least not for me):

```
<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
    Storyboard.TargetName="itemListView"
    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.ColumnSpan)">
    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1" />
</ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

It showed up that this kind of property should be enclosed in parentheses.